# Passing another div element as arguement to jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm basically trying to do a dropdown jquery plugin.

### HTML

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<div id="clickDiv">Click Me</div>
<div id="nav">
    <span>settings</br></span>
    <span>Preferences</br></span>
    <span>Logout</br></span>        
</div>
```

### Script (script.js)

```
$('#clickDiv').click(function() {
   $('#nav').dDown({
          parent : '#clickDiv'; 
   });  
});
```

### Plugin script

```
$.fn.dDown = function(parent) { 
    var options = {
        parent : ''
    };

    if(parent) {
        $x = $(parent);
        console.log($x.css('top'));  //Get the top position of the #clickDiv
    }
};
```

How can i get the properties of the element .. line $x.css('top') throws error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parent` variable is an object, like options. You have to use:

```
$.fn.dDown = function(options) {  //<--- Renamed "parent" to "options"
    options = jQuery.extend({
        parent : ''
    }, options);                  //<--- Implementing default values

    var $x = $(options.parent);
    if ($x.length) { // <-- Check if the selectors matches anything
        console.log($x.css('top'));  //Get the top position of the #clickDiv
    }
};
```

The code works well, but you should **not** define it as a jQuery plugin, since it does **nothing** with the `this` object. Propery defined jQuery plugins are often chainable, and act on all elements in the jQuery collection.